# How are PCSC smart card reader 'friendly names' constructed?

Tags: c#, .net, smartcard-reader, pcsc, winscard

I use WinSCard to list all readers, which gives me a list like this:

```
ASK RDR4x7 0
SCM Microsystems Inc. SCR3320 USB Smart Card Reader 0
SCM Microsystems Inc. SCR3320 USB Smart Card Reader 1
SCM Microsystems Inc. SCR3320 USB Smart Card Reader 2
```

Which is great, but I have no clue which name belongs to which card reader.

**Where do these names come from? How are they constructed?**

What I've found up until now: in the registry, there is a `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` key. Under this key, you can find the subkey which matches the card reader's "service" (which I found by querying the WMI registry). For example: the service for the `SCM Microsystems Inc. SCR3320 USB Smart Card Reader` readers is `SCR3XX2K`.

This subkey (`SCR3XX2K`) has another subkey `Enum`, which has multiple interesting values:

- `Count`: DWORD,  the number of readers connected
- `0`, `1`, `2`: STRING, hardware Device ID

I guess these are the numbers appended to the 'friendly names', but I can't figure out how the name string is constructed. I need this to map hardware Device ID's (which I get through WMI) to their friendly name.

**So, what's the pattern used to create a 'friendly name' for a smart card reader, and where do the values come from?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are a concatination of these 3 attributes:

```
SCARD_ATTR_VENDOR_NAME
SCARD_ATTR_VENDOR_IFD_TYPE
SCARD_ATTR_DEVICE_UNIT
```

The TechNet article [Smart Card Events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff404292%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) documents this in the "Smart Card reader name" section.

`SCARD_???` attributes are requested with the `SCardGetAttrib` [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The `SCARD_ATTR_DEVICE_SYSTEM_NAME` attribute returns the `friendly name` as the ones you get while listing the readers.

The list of SmartCard readers exists in the registry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\Readers`. Readers are added to this list by the INF file of the SCR driver, so during driver installation.

A link between device and reader can be found in the SmartCardReader class `{50DD5230-BA8A-11D1-BF5D-0000F805F530}` under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{50DD5230-BA8A-11D1-BF5D-0000F805F5‌​30}`.