# How to connect to Smart Card Reader based on its USB port location?

Tags: c#, smartcard-reader, winscard

I'm currently doing some research and testing on multiple smart card reader identification to determine which reader is connected to which USB port.

Lets say that I plug in Reader A into USB port 1. By invoking SCardListReaders function, I retrieve the following friendly name:

> - ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader PICC 0

Then I plug in another reader (Reader B) into USB port 2. Now I have 2 readers connected to the same PC. Invoking SCardListReaders will give me:

> - ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader PICC 0
> - ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader PICC 1

I'm aware of how these names are generated ([How are PCSC smart card reader 'friendly names' constructed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813041/how-are-pcsc-smart-card-reader-friendly-names-constructedhttp://)) and I know that plugging in the readers in different sequence (plug in Reader B first then Reader A) will change the SCARD_ATTR_DEVICE_UNIT thus affecting the friendly names.

Based on the above scenario, **how can I ensure that the PC will always automatically connect to PICC reader in USB port 1 regardless of its friendly name?**

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome new user. Note that there are limited number of persons available on this site for this particular purpose. Personally I would try and work around this issue; e.g. if you have a particular smart card in one reader, try to make a decision based on the ATR of that card.

Comment: Can't you use some reader-specific API to get the reader serial number (or any other identifier) and use it to distinguish the readers?