# The implementation of SCardGetReaderDeviceInstanceId

Tags: c++, smartcard, setupapi

Microsoft implements [`SCardGetReaderDeviceInstanceId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448500(v=vs.85).aspx) in winscard.dll on Windows8 and later version. I really want to know the implementation of this function. I tried to decompile it but am not good at decompilation, I got nothing. I am asking because I have a requirement to correlate smartcard reader Name with DeviceInstanceId, so I think I may able to implement it on Windows7 or even older version based on its implementation on Windows8. So folks, anyhelp?

```
LONG WINAPI SCardGetReaderDeviceInstanceId(
  _In_      SCARDCONTEXT hContext,
  _In_      LPCTSTR      szReaderName,
  _Out_opt_ LPTSTR       szDeviceInstanceId,
  _Inout_   LPDWORD      cchDeviceInstanceId
);
```

Comment: Here is a question similar to my requirement. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401845/how-to-connect-to-smart-card-reader-based-on-its-usb-port-location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253830/how-to-find-the-device-instance-id-of-a-pcsc-reader). It seems that your requirement isn't possible to finish on Windows7 and older version.

Comment: Ok... but, how about the implementation of `SCardGetReaderDeviceInstanceId`, any idea?