# Smartcard reader ACR122U has no unique serial number

Tags: usb, debian, nfc, smartcard, pcsc

I am using the PCSC driver and the javax.smartcardio library as the wrapper to the driver. I have 3 ACR122U devices plugged into a Linux (debian) system. I have ran udevadm info on the devices and they all have a serial number of 0. I need to identify which reader is which in my class. I can check which topological usb port is used by parsing the /sys/devices folder but I still cant "select" a device in the Java api.

Does anyone know a way to modify the PCSC device stack order or something. So that I can specify which order the devices are in the terminal list from the terminal factory. I have emailed ACS asking them why the serial numbers are 0 and if they can help me to modify it but I have had no reply.

Please let me know if anyone thinks they have a solution.
Thanks,
Mitch

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813041/how-are-pcsc-smart-card-reader-friendly-names-constructed) of any help?

Comment: Hello? Anybody there?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately all of the attributes amongst the readers are exactly the same so no. I did email ACS and they couldn't really help me either. I ended up parsing the usb topology to find the correct dev number for the usb port. I then used that dev number to ensure I always used the right reader.

Answer (score 1):

The reader does have a unique serial number but it is only an external sticker and not on the readers internal EEPROM.  Perhaps you can write the serial number to the reader somehow.